# Scala equivalent of flags

Tags: scala, flags, enum-flags

Isn't there an equivalent for flags in Scala ?

Something like :

```
val flags = Something | SomeOtherThing
```

I guess I could do a class for each flag set and have a bunch of booleans but what about syntactic sugar?

Comment: Hmm, I answered not thinking about DSLs, which might be more what you are looking for. If you want syntactic sugar for flags, you can try looking up how you define DSLs and override operators in Scala. I've just started using the language and, unfortunately, I'm unable to help you very much here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It largely depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

**If you're interfacing with legacy code** (especially one that you cannot modify) **and/or need super-extra-high efficiency** ([you usually don't](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29)), [a canonical way](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.swing.event.Key%24@Modifiers=Int) **is to create a type alias for `Int`**. I.e., as in the linked library example:

```
type MyFlags = Int
...
val theseFlags: MyFlags
```

The advantage over merely using `Int` is that you can "mark" any usage of those flags with the type alias - this can help immensely with code readability and help avoid bugs due to "mixing up" flags.

For this approach, within Scala-specific code, you can assist yourself by (ab)using [BitSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.BitSet) (more info [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html)).

---

**If you want to create a more "object-friendly" implementation, the solution is similar to Java's `enum`/`EnumSet` combo** - namely, **use [`Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.Enumeration) with `ValueSet`** . An example adapted from the library doc:

```
scala>   object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
     |     type WeekDay = Value
     |     val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = WeekDay
     |   }
defined module WeekDay

scala>   import WeekDay._
import WeekDay._

scala> var newSet = ValueSet.empty
newSet: WeekDay.ValueSet = WeekDay.ValueSet()

scala> newSet += Mon

scala> newSet
res1: WeekDay.ValueSet = WeekDay.ValueSet(Mon)

scala> newSet & WeekDay.values
res2: WeekDay.ValueSet = WeekDay.ValueSet(Mon)
```

A problem with `ValueSet` and `Value` arises - **their lack of type-parametrization allows for mixing two different types of flags**. Of course, this is only a deficiency when compared to Java's `EnumSet`. In the context of Scala, the workaround is exactly the same as in the `Int` example - use a `type` alias, this time for `Value` (as shown above).

And as an added bonus, **all your flags have unique names**.

---

As a *pro-forma*, I should also mention [Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). Together with a type alias, they would allow you to add custom operators to your flags while preserving the efficiency of `Int`s.

However, that's likely an overkill for most usage scenarios - you're usually better off using the second, `Enumeration`-based approach. It should be sufficiently efficient for most cases, **especially since [`ValueSet` is really a thin wrapper around `BitSet`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L83)**.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much complete I guess.
I have seen Enumerations and I wondered if there was some type dedicated to flags (but probably named differently as I couldn't find anything). I'll use them, it is just for a few options in my program.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Something` or `SomeOtherThing` are numbers, this should work.

If you want to make it more obvious, try specifying the type:

`val flags : Int = Something | SomeOtherThing`

Bitwise operators should work in Scala pretty much like they work in Java. I've found [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_bitwise_operators.htm) brief explanation on Google, which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You may run into a lot of confusing error messages about conflicts between `Weekday.type` and `Weekday.Value` if you don't update one line from the mikolak's post.

Update

```
val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = WeekDay
```

to

```
val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
```